# Running SSIS Package in C# Error

Tags: c#, ssis

I get this error message when trying to run a SSIS package in C#. The error is:

> Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/SSIS.Pipeline : To run a SSIS
>   package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.

I checked the development machine and the server, and both have the SSDT installed. The target SQL Server is 2012, and I ran a report to check the edition of Integration Services that is running and it is the Standard Edition (11.3.6020.0). I noticed that the error occurs when it runs the data flow tasks that implement some derived column transformations. Any ideas on how to fix this issue? Thanks for your help!

Here is my C# code:

```
class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
{
    public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent,
      string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
    {
        // Add application-specific diagnostics here.  
        Console.WriteLine("Error in {0}/{1} : {2}", source, subComponent, description);
        return false;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
             GetExtractsData();            
    }


    static void GetExtractsData()
    {
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();

        pkgLocation = @"C:\Package.dtsx";
        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
        pkg.EnableConfigurations = true;
        Configuration config = pkg.Configurations.Add();

        config.ConfigurationType = DTSConfigurationType.ConfigFile;
        config.ConfigurationString=@"C:\Extracts_Config.dtsConfig";
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);

        Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("The Extracts completed downloading at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: does SSIS package executes without any error from Visual Studio ?

Comment: I was able to execute the SSIS packages in Visual Studio with no errors.When I was developing the packages and before deployment, I was able to run the package within Visual Studio without error and issues.

Comment: Unreproducible.  You say you are running this package on a server that has standard edition SSIS Service running, and the error says otherwise.  No way we can troubleshoot without seeing your server.  You should open a ticket with Microsoft, if you're sure you are running the package on a SSIS Server.

Comment: Is the Integration Services service itself running (or 'stopped')? Also it could be that the assemblies you're using are for a different version of SQL Server- worth checking